# Setting up Django on Elastic Beanstalk with Postgres

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, django-settings, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How should I set up my `settings.py` file for Django on EC2 Elastic Beanstalk to use a Postgres RDS ?

[These docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python_django.html) only give the `settings.py` for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably just need to change the engine setting  in your databases object. you will need to install psycopg2 to your environment. Here is what mine looks like. just fill in your db's info.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': '',        # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',        # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                 # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                 # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not quite sure that I follow what the values should be for NAME, HOST, etc. I would think they should NOT be blank but rather should look like the settings for MySQL?:`'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME']`

Comment: This is a decent start: http://ashokfernandez.wordpress.com/2014/03/11/deploying-a-django-app-to-amazon-aws-with-nginx-gunicorn-git/

Answer (score 0):

Use psycopg2, and use environment variables (made available for you within Elastic Beanstalk):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
        'USER': os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
        'PASSWORD': os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD'],
        'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
        'PORT': os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
    }
}
```

You'll need to include psycopg2 in a pip requirements.txt file (made using `pip freeze > requirements.txt`) and likely also install a Postgres dependency, postgresql-devel, by including the following in an .ebextensions/package.config file (the filename doesn't have to be packages.config, that's just what I use):

```
packages:
  yum:
    postgresql-devel: []
```

Comment: I'm getting an error that "yum doesn't contain postgresql-devel"!!

Comment: I had that issue too. I think there's a problem with the 2014-09 Linux build. Choose 2014-03 and it should work.

Comment: Try postgresql92-devel or postgresql93-devel with 2014-09